# Sending an array from a content script to the background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to send an array from my content script to the background page, so that it can be stored and called upon later from the popup using chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().

At the moment, my background page looks like this (based on an example from the developer website).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

      function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {

        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
        sendResponse({});
      };

      chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);

    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

My content script performs a few simple regexes, and if it finds a match responds with:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({}, function(response) {});
```

What I would like to do is send an array created by the content script back to the background page. I'm somewhat stumped as to how to go about this. Do I need to create a second request, or can I send the array along with the response above.

Thank you all for your help. This is my first time posting here, though I've long benefited from the questions and answers posted by others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array of matches is called `matches`, your content script could use something like:

```js
chrome.extension.sendRequest({matches: matches}, function(response) {});
```

Then in your background page, you can extract the matches array from the request:

```js
function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var matches = request.matches;
  // do stuff with the matches array here
  sendResponse({});
};
```

Generally, whatever data you put into the `request` argument of `chrome.extension.sendRequest` will be passed to your `onRequest` function. See the extension documentation about [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) for more details.