# How do I pass the entire dom as an object from a content script to the background page in xml and html?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I can get it working in html by converting it to a string and then sending it like this:

```
messages = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML;
```

However, I have no idea what the xml equivalent of this is. I've tried a few things that I thought would work but they don't. For example, this reads as undefined when it is sent back to the background page:

```
messages = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
sendResponse({messages: document});
```

Also, I can't get it working by passing it as an object in either language, and I do believe that I can pass objects between the background page and the content script because of questions like these:
[Sending an array from a content script to the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533242/sending-an-array-from-a-content-script-to-the-background-page)

For example, while `messages = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML;` works just fine, this doesn't work at all in either xml or html: `sendResponse({messages: document});`

it reads `response.messages` as undefined

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text && (msg.text == "report_back_ls")) {
          //messages = document.getElementsByTagName("rss")[0];//

          //messages = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);

          //var s = new XMLSerializer();
          //var str = s.serializeToString(document);
          //alert(str);


                    sendResponse({messages: document});
    }
});
```

Comment: As [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) says only JSON-serializable objects can be sent. Which excludes DOM elements.

Comment: Also the second code in your question doesn't make any sense. The result of XMLSerializer isn't used in the actual message because in `{messages: document}` the string `messages` denotes a literal name of the key, not a variable. See Javascript syntax for literal objects.

Comment: sorry, I should have explained that the code I was using for testing the XMLSerializer was:chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.text && (msg.text == "report_back_ls")) {
          //messages = document.getElementsByTagName("rss")[0];//

          //messages = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);

          //var s = new XMLSerializer();
          //var str = s.serializeToString(document);
          //alert(str);


     sendResponse({messages: messages});
    }
});

Comment: thanks very much for pointing this out! I thought it would either be only strings or all objects, I forgot it could be only JSON-serializable objects